# Trigger en vue js y laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy realizando una sección de editar el select de municipio y ciudad los selecciono con esta función:

```
  $("#departamento").val('{{$usuario->fk_id_departamento}}').trigger("change");
```

la cual funciona pero al realizar el change la función que empleo con Vue para que me cargue los municipios correspondientes a ese departamento no se ejecuta pero si realizo el change manual si funciona esta es la función de vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#aplicacion',
    data: {
        departamento:'',
        municipios:[],
      },
      methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
            this.municipios = [];
            var id = event.target.value;
            var url = 'https://localhost/todojuegos/todojuegos/public/municipio/'+id;
            axios.get(url)
              .then(response => {
                this.municipios = response.data;
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
      },
});
```

de que forma puedo hacer que el valor obtenido de departamento al realizar el change con el trigger automaticamente se ejecute el método  greet de Vue y me cargue los municipios.

Comment: Tienes que cambiar el observable tambien, no solo el objeto jQuery.  Si agregas mas codigo talvez pueda ayudarte.

Comment: que otro código requieres..?

Comment: El codigo en donde haces esto: `$("#departamento").val('{{$usuario->fk_id_departamento}}').trigger("change");`

Comment: `<script>
                                $("#departamento").on('change',function(){
                                  //aqui anterior mente ejecutaba una funcion ajax para traer los municipios pero se migro a vue no quiero repetir codigo  
                                });
                                $("#departamento").val('{{$usuario->fk_id_departamento}}').trigger("change");
                                
</script>`

Comment: ese es todo el código jquery lo único que hace recibir el valor `{{$usuario->fk_id_departamento}}` y ese valor hace que el select cambie a la opción que recibe de la base de datos

Comment: Como es que tienes el `.trigger("change")` dentro del `.on('change')`? Que eso no seria un loop infinito?

Comment: no, esta por fuera primero es el change y luego es el trigger igual en el change no tengo nada es solo unas pruebas que realice pues llevo horas tratando de hacer que al ejecutar el trigger vue ejecute el metodo greet

Comment: Y en el HTML llamas a la funcion greet?

Comment: el metodo greet es el encargado de traer los municipios de ese departamento si yo cambio el departamente de forma manual el metodo vue funciona pero si disparo el evento con el trigger no carga nada en el select de municipios

Comment: `<select @change="greet" id="departamento" name="departamento" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('departamento') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" required>`

Comment: y debe esta funcionando por que como te indico si yo mismo realizo un cambio en el select de departamente el me carga los municipios el problema esta es cuando realizo el cambio desde el trigger

Comment: revisa este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917889/is-it-possible-to-trigger-events-using-vue-js